# ImportError: ImportError: cannot import name 'PointConv' from 'torch_geometric.nn'

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda

I am having a problem with dMaSIF ([Link to repo](https://github.com/FreyrS/dMaSIF/tree/master)) while trying to run the MaSIF-search. I am getting this error:

```
  File "/home/ec2-user/operations/packages/dMaSIF/benchmark_scripts/../main_training.py", line 13, in <module>
    from model import dMaSIF
  File "/home/ec2-user/operations/packages/dMaSIF/model.py", line 16, in <module>
    from benchmark_models import DGCNN_seg, PointNet2_seg, dMaSIFConv_seg
  File "/home/ec2-user/operations/packages/dMaSIF/benchmark_models.py", line 14, in <module>
    from torch_geometric.nn import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'PointConv' from 'torch_geometric.nn' (/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch_geometric/nn/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/operations/packages/dMaSIF/benchmark_scripts/../main_training.py", line 13, in <module>
    from model import dMaSIF
  File "/home/ec2-user/operations/packages/dMaSIF/model.py", line 16, in <module>
    from benchmark_models import DGCNN_seg, PointNet2_seg, dMaSIFConv_seg
  File "/home/ec2-user/operations/packages/dMaSIF/benchmark_models.py", line 14, in <module>
    from torch_geometric.nn import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'PointConv' from 'torch_geometric.nn' (/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch_geometric/nn/__init__.py)
```

I have tried to reinstall torch_geometric, but it did not work. It seems like an error in torch_geometric...

Comment: Please don't share code links, add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead

Comment: Also it might depend on the version of torch you have installed and was used by the original repo users as I see [torch_geometric.nn.conv](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/conv/point_conv.html)